# Flask is not printing sys.stdout.write messages

Tags: python, logging, flask

I am running the flask app from this [link](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/REST-tutorial/blob/master/rest-server-v2.py) using the command `python app.py`.

More logs printed using, `sys.stdout.write` are not printed on the console. However using `logging.StreamHandler` works for redirecting messages to stdout.

It works,

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger('kumologging')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.info("hey, i am from logger obj")
```

It doesn't work

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hey, i am from stdout")
```

Does flask override sys.stdout file descriptor, redirecting the logs elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

afaik flasks `app.run()` uses the `gunicorn` web package

I believe gunicorn is the one that is actually redirecting your output

the output might be in `/var/log/gunicorn/error.log` (not sure where it would be on windows :/)

or its possible `sys.stdout` is just not flushing its buffer,
try `sys.stdout.flush()` after writting to it

Comment: hey sorry man, it looks like sys.stdout buffers sizeably.. i had to use `sys.stdout.flush` to make it appear onscreen

Comment: meh than this probably shouldnt be the accepted answer ... :P I would just unaccept my answer ... and perhaps answer it yourself when it lets you :)

Comment: i marked it as accepted, because i can't delete my question anymore and i didn't want others wasting their time on it... thanks, your clues helped me to debug it better....

Comment: No reason to delete it - Instead of wasting time, I found it usefull and it saved my time. Furthermore, I agree with @joran-beasley that the accepted answer should hold the answer in the main text, not in the comments, as it is now.