# strange behavior with flask on windows

Tags: python, windows, flask, cmd

I'm maintaining a web application built with Flask with python 2.7 coupled with Jinja and angularjs .In a Linux environment, everything is working fine.

On windows when I run the application on cmd or git bash (python app.py), I only see that the server is running and in which port (and everything else is working fine in the browser), but the problem is that the logs in console aren't shown like in a Linux terminal. 
For example, I can't see the requests like: POST  /login..or an exceptional mission or even a simple print "test" Dosen"to show (still everything is working in a browser).

Even worst, when I terminate the server with "ctr+c" all the previous messages and logs are printed in the terminal, all together in one single dump!

--- Update ---
when i use the command python -u app.py 
it's even worst , the application dose'nt run in the browser anymore , no log in console and when i termiante it shows this :
[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C36FE.png)

Comment: Dupe? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326236/flask-is-not-printing-sys-stdout-write-messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326236/flask-is-not-printing-sys-stdout-write-messages)

Comment: @PatrickArtner i didnt understand what do you mean by flush() is it a python function ? even the link is not well explained , i'm printing like this : print "hello"+x

Comment: thanks , with this information i can search for it more .

Comment: @PatrickArtner so i have to write "sys.stdout.flush()" after every methode or a print call ? is there a way to make it more global ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925451/flask-logging-not-working-at-all

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you creat a proper uWSGI gateway.

An example setup could be:

```
Linux 18.04 -> 
Nginx / Apache reverse web proxy mode -> 
Gunicorn (which has a debugger you can attach, this will output to the regular log files like other applications. Systemd logs I think) -> 
Flask web framework.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: as i said it works fine in linux , but i need to make it work in windows too , even in a dev mode it's more convenient for me .

Comment: If you run the application from the CLI then `print()` should output to the CLI after it boots the internal web server. I often troubleshoot things with Flask apps running in dev env locally with it.

Comment: yeah , but 'print' doesn't print anything for me from the CLI . it only prints when i terminate .

Comment: You must be calling a blocking command somewhere then. For example time.sleep() is not asynchronous and will make the entire app hang in a similar way (not necessarily the answer) but something along those lines.

Comment: Are you using a uWSGI gateway?

Comment: No i'm not using a uWSGI Gateway in the devEnv (windows) but i'm using wsgi_mod with apach in the production mode in our VPS